# How can I answer questions in StackOverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, answers

Hi,

I'm a 5 year experience .NET developer. But I can't answer many C# questions in StackOVerflow. In rare cases that I could answer something, there would be completer answers to that question!

How can I answer more question in C# or even ASP.NET?

Comment: ... and get things done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest [browsing the tags list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/) and looking for less popular tags that you have a good breadth of knowledge in. When browsing by tag, use the **Related Tags** sidebar on the right to narrow. Clicking multiple times here will combine the tags so you get increasingly more narrow in focus.

The [unanswered question page](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) is also useful -- and, similarly, try narrowing it down via the **Unanswered Tags** sidebar on the right. It works the same as the related tags sidebar, above, so click multiple times to get more narrow.